# Android Navigation back button dispatcher wierd behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm using the Navigation Components and am trying to just listen to the back button from a fragment; Before listening, everything works fine meaning both the toolbar button and the native back button navigate to the previous fragment as expected.

So, to add a listener, I followed this: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back and added a callback in my fragment like so:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceBundle: Bundle?){
    // saveIfNew when back button is pressed
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this){
        viewModel.checkAndSave()
    }
}
```

After doing that, the native back button no longer works, but the toolbar back does work as expected.  The docs on that page seem to make it seem like this was just a listener and shouldn't be affecting the navigation chain, so what am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

You want to disable your `OnBackPressedCallback` when you don't require it to intercept the back button anymore. To do so, use `setEnabled(boolean)` method. You can also completely remove your callback by calling `remove()`.

In addition, if you just want to save & exit current fragment you can use `findNavController().navigateUp()` inside the `handleOnBackPressed` method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceBundle: Bundle?){
    // saveIfNew when back button is pressed
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this){
        viewModel.checkAndSave()
        findNavController().navigateUp()
    }
}
```